# Is this a correct abreviation of the singular value decomposition algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

I want to describe the process as:

For an $m\times n$ matrix A:

- Compute $A^TA$ and $AA^T$
- $U=$ orthogonally diagonalize $AA^T$
- $V=$ orthgononally diagonalize $A^TA$
- $\Sigma =$ "Diagonal" $m\times n$ matrix of the singular values
- $A=U\Sigma V^T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

You get the singular values by looking at the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ or $A^TA$.  (They are the same.  They are all real and positive because both matrices are positive semi-definite.)

The matrix $\Sigma$ inherits the shape of $A$, and it looks like this:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_1 &0 & \cdots\\
0 & \ddots & 0  \\
0 & \cdots & \sigma_n\\
0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$
or its transpose.  The point is that there is a block of zero on the bottom or on the right.

Comment: According to the guy just above you I am wrong :p